# XMind Zen freezes on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed XMind Zen using the deb file on ubuntu 18.10. However it freezes up whenever I try to use the minimize/maximize button or the menus at top or the scroll bars.

I tried adding a new relationship on a given mindmap and the screen went blank.

I am on Hp Spectre x360 with NVidia GeForce MX150 graphic card, if that is of some help in debugging.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?